# Batch code not working for space in the file name

Tags: batch-file

Trying to automate using batch file wherein it will display filename and number of records in the file in an Output.txt file.But if my filename has space, then it does not give number of records, instead it show the text following the space

```
@echo off


(
for %%n IN (*.*) do ( 
  for /F "tokens=3" %%f in ('find /V /C "-------------" "%%n"') do (

   echo %%n : %%f
  ) 
))  >output.txt
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

just use `tokens=2,*`, ignore token2. `*` means "take all the rest without tokenizing any more"

```
@echo off
(
  for %%n IN (*.*) do ( 
    for /F "tokens=2 delims=:" %%f in ('find /V /C "-------------" "%%n"') do (
      echo %%n :%%f
    )
  )
)  >output.txt
```

Comment: Thank You. This is now giving the count

Comment: Thank You. This is now giving the count .
but for the file with space, it gives output, filename : test after space in file name : count. How do I get just the file name?
RTMCDS29_CLARUS_9_REEXTRACTION 2016.txt : 2016.TXT: 12678

Comment: just `echo %%g` (if you can live with filenames in all capitals) or use edited solution.