# Modify Windows batch file to count lines

Tags: windows, batch-file, cmd

I have this code:

```
@echo off

:CountLines
setlocal
set /a totalNumLines = 0
for /r %1 %%F in (*.txt) do (
  for /f %%N in ('find /v /c "" ^<"%%F"') do set /a totalNumLines+=%%N
)

echo Total number of code lines for %1 = %totalNumLines% >>log.txt
```

This counts all the lines in the files and gives me the total number of lines. However, I need it to give the filename and lines for each file, not the total.

the desired output is a bit like this:

```
FILEA.txt 1200
FILEB.txt 300
FILEC.txt 10
```

Comment: Please read [Under what circumstances may I add “urgent” or other similar phrases to my question, in order to obtain faster answers?](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/326569) - the summary is that this is not an ideal way to address volunteers, and is probably counterproductive to obtaining answers. Please refrain from adding this to your questions.

Comment: [related question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45481636/batch-code-not-working-for-space-in-the-file-name/45481800#45481800)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the answer myself after a lot of trial and error:

```
@echo off

:CountLines
setlocal
set /a totalNumLines = 0
for /r %1 %%F in (*.txt) do (
  for /f %%N in ('find /v /c "" ^<"%%F"') do echo %%N >>log.txt
)
```

Answer (score 2):

Your answer doesn't output the filename:

```
@echo off & Setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion
Set /A TotalNumLines=0
( For /R %1 %%F In (*.Txt) Do (
      For /F %%N In ('Find /V /C "" ^<"%%F"') Do (
          Echo %%F %%N
          Set /A TotalNumLines+=%%N
      ) 
  )
  Echo Total number of code lines for all files = !TotalNumLines!
) > log.txt
EndLocal
```